# I'm trying to do real time object detection and tracking in MATLAB. But it's giving me error

Tags: computer-vision, matlab-cvst, video-tracking

```
function multiObjectTracking()
```

% create system objects used for reading video, detecting moving objects,
% and displaying the results

```
obj = setupSystemObjects();

tracks = initializeTracks(); % create an empty array of tracks

nextId = 1; % ID of the next track
```

% detect moving objects, and track them across video frames

```
while ~isDone(obj.reader)
    frame = readFrame();
    [centroids, bboxes, mask] = detectObjects(frame);
    predictNewLocationsOfTracks();
    [assignments, unassignedTracks, unassignedDetections] = ...
        detectionToTrackAssignment();

    updateAssignedTracks();
    updateUnassignedTracks();
    deleteLostTracks();
    createNewTracks();

    displayTrackingResults();
end
```

%% Create System Objects
% Create System objects used for reading the video frames, detecting
% foreground objects, and displaying results.

```
    function obj = setupSystemObjects()
```

% Initialize Video I/O
% Create objects for reading a video from a file, drawing the tracked
% objects in each frame, and playing the video.

```
        vid = videoinput('winvideo', 1, 'YUY2_320x240');
        src = getselectedsource(vid);

        vid.FramesPerTrigger = 1;
```

% TriggerRepeat is zero based and is always one
% less than the number of triggers.

```
        vid.TriggerRepeat = 899;

        preview(vid);

        start(vid);

        stoppreview(vid);

        savedvideo = getdata(vid);
```

% create a video file reader

```
        obj.reader = vision.VideoFileReader(savedvideo);
```

% create two video players, one to display the video,
% and one to display the foreground mask

```
        obj.videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer('Position', [20, 400, 700, 400]);
        obj.maskPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer('Position', [740, 400, 700, 400]);

        obj.detector = vision.ForegroundDetector('NumGaussians', 3, ...
            'NumTrainingFrames', 40, 'MinimumBackgroundRatio', 0.7);

        obj.blobAnalyser = vision.BlobAnalysis('BoundingBoxOutputPort', true, ...
            'AreaOutputPort', true, 'CentroidOutputPort', true, ...
            'MinimumBlobArea', 400);
    end

    function tracks = initializeTracks()
```

% create an empty array of tracks

```
        tracks = struct(...
            'id', {}, ...
            'bbox', {}, ...
            'kalmanFilter', {}, ...
            'age', {}, ...
            'totalVisibleCount', {}, ...
            'consecutiveInvisibleCount', {});
    end
```

%% Read a Video Frame
% Read the next video frame from the video file.

```
    function frame = readFrame()
        frame = obj.reader.step();
    end


    function [centroids, bboxes, mask] = detectObjects(frame)
```

% detect foreground

```
        mask = obj.detector.step(frame);
```

% apply morphological operations to remove noise and fill in holes

```
        mask = imopen(mask, strel('rectangle', [3,3]));
        mask = imclose(mask, strel('rectangle', [15, 15])); 
        mask = imfill(mask, 'holes');
```

% perform blob analysis to find connected components

```
        [~, centroids, bboxes] = obj.blobAnalyser.step(mask);
    end
```

%% Predict New Locations of Existing Tracks
% Use the Kalman filter to predict the centroid of each track in the
% current frame, and update its bounding box accordingly.

```
    function predictNewLocationsOfTracks()
        for i = 1:length(tracks)
            bbox = tracks(i).bbox;
```

% predict the current location of the track

```
            predictedCentroid = predict(tracks(i).kalmanFilter);
```

% shift the bounding box so that its center is at 
% the predicted location

```
            predictedCentroid = int32(predictedCentroid) - bbox(3:4) / 2;
            tracks(i).bbox = [predictedCentroid, bbox(3:4)];
        end
    end


    function [assignments, unassignedTracks, unassignedDetections] = ...
            detectionToTrackAssignment()

        nTracks = length(tracks);
        nDetections = size(centroids, 1);
```

% compute the cost of assigning each detection to each track

```
        cost = zeros(nTracks, nDetections);
        for i = 1:nTracks
            cost(i, :) = distance(tracks(i).kalmanFilter, centroids);
        end
```

% solve the assignment problem

```
        costOfNonAssignment = 20;
        [assignments, unassignedTracks, unassignedDetections] = ...
            assignDetectionsToTracks(cost, costOfNonAssignment);
    end

    function updateAssignedTracks()
        numAssignedTracks = size(assignments, 1);
        for i = 1:numAssignedTracks
            trackIdx = assignments(i, 1);
            detectionIdx = assignments(i, 2);
            centroid = centroids(detectionIdx, :);
            bbox = bboxes(detectionIdx, :);
```

% correct the estimate of the object's location
% using the new detection

```
            correct(tracks(trackIdx).kalmanFilter, centroid);
```

% replace predicted bounding box with detected
% bounding box

```
            tracks(trackIdx).bbox = bbox;
```

% update track's age

```
            tracks(trackIdx).age = tracks(trackIdx).age + 1;
```

% update visibility

```
            tracks(trackIdx).totalVisibleCount = ...
                tracks(trackIdx).totalVisibleCount + 1;
            tracks(trackIdx).consecutiveInvisibleCount = 0;
        end
    end
```

%% Update Unassigned Tracks
% Mark each unassigned track as invisible, and increase its age by 1.

```
    function updateUnassignedTracks()
        for i = 1:length(unassignedTracks)
            ind = unassignedTracks(i);
            tracks(ind).age = tracks(ind).age + 1;
            tracks(ind).consecutiveInvisibleCount = ...
                tracks(ind).consecutiveInvisibleCount + 1;
        end
    end


    function deleteLostTracks()
        if isempty(tracks)
            return;
        end

        invisibleForTooLong = 10;
        ageThreshold = 8;
```

% compute the fraction of the track's age for which it was visible

```
        ages = [tracks(:).age];
        totalVisibleCounts = [tracks(:).totalVisibleCount];
        visibility = totalVisibleCounts ./ ages;
```

% find the indices of 'lost' tracks

```
        lostInds = (ages < ageThreshold & visibility < 0.6) | ...
            [tracks(:).consecutiveInvisibleCount] >= invisibleForTooLong;
```

% delete lost tracks

```
        tracks = tracks(~lostInds);
    end

    function createNewTracks()
        centroids = centroids(unassignedDetections, :);
        bboxes = bboxes(unassignedDetections, :);

        for i = 1:size(centroids, 1)

            centroid = centroids(i,:);
            bbox = bboxes(i, :);
```

% create a Kalman filter object

```
            kalmanFilter = configureKalmanFilter('ConstantVelocity', ...
                centroid, [200, 50], [100, 25], 100);
```

% create a new track

```
            newTrack = struct(...
                'id', nextId, ...
                'bbox', bbox, ...
                'kalmanFilter', kalmanFilter, ...
                'age', 1, ...
                'totalVisibleCount', 1, ...
                'consecutiveInvisibleCount', 0);
```

% add it to the array of tracks

```
            tracks(end + 1) = newTrack;
```

% increment the next id

```
            nextId = nextId + 1;
        end
    end

    function displayTrackingResults()
```

% convert the frame and the mask to uint8 RGB

```
        frame = im2uint8(frame);
        mask = uint8(repmat(mask, [1, 1, 3])) .* 255;

        minVisibleCount = 8;
        if ~isempty(tracks)
```

% noisy detections tend to result in short-lived tracks
% only display tracks that have been visible for more than 
% a minimum number of frames.

```
            reliableTrackInds = ...
                [tracks(:).totalVisibleCount] > minVisibleCount;
            reliableTracks = tracks(reliableTrackInds);
```

% display the objects. If an object has not been detected
% in this frame, display its predicted bounding box.

```
            if ~isempty(reliableTracks)
```

% get bounding boxes

```
                bboxes = cat(1, reliableTracks.bbox);
```

% get ids

```
                ids = int32([reliableTracks(:).id]);
```

% create labels for objects indicating the ones for 
% which we display the predicted rather than the actual 
% location

```
                labels = cellstr(int2str(ids'));
                predictedTrackInds = ...
                    [reliableTracks(:).consecutiveInvisibleCount] > 0;
                isPredicted = cell(size(labels));
                isPredicted(predictedTrackInds) = {' predicted'};
                labels = strcat(labels, isPredicted);
```

% draw on the frame

```
                frame = insertObjectAnnotation(frame, 'rectangle', ...
                    bboxes, labels);
```

% draw on the mask

```
                mask = insertObjectAnnotation(mask, 'rectangle', ...
                    bboxes, labels);
            end
        end
```

% display the mask and the frame

```
        obj.maskPlayer.step(mask);        
        obj.videoPlayer.step(frame);
    end

displayEndOfDemoMessage(mfilename)
end
```

Comment: By the way, there is no optical flow here. You may want to edit your question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to use `vision.VideoFileReader`, while trying to read frames from a camera.  `vision.VideoFileReader` is only for reading video files.  If you are getting frames from the camera you do not need it at all.  You should add your `videoinput` object to the `obj` struct, and you should try using `getsnapshot` inside `readFrame()`.

Comment: please tell me how can i add my real time video in this code..?

Comment: I already did. You can call `getsnapshot(vid)` to get each video frame.